# Share facebook wall on a website

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

Is it possible to share facebook wall on side a website? I would like to let each logged in user on my site to view his facebook wall on a certain area. IF the user is not logged in to facebook I want him to login , then this will allow him to view his wall. I don't need other that his wall to be displayed in my site.

How possible is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to share facebook wall on side a website?

Yes.

> IF the user is not logged in to facebook I want him to login , then this will allow him to view his wall. I don't need other that his wall to be displayed in my site.

Use [Facebook Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api) to serve your purpose. Do this:

1. Add a Facebook login button to your website using [Facebook Authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) refer [**Login** subheading here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/)
2. Make sure you ask for [Advanced Permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) from your user to allow your application to use his `read_stream`. This will allow your app to access logged-in user's posts that includes his wall posts. See details [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/)
3. Parse the JSON object and display. You may want to have a long-poll or AJAX call ready to poll the new messages at regular intervals.